# Mapbox performance with 50k markers via JSON

Tags: javascript, json, mapbox

So I'm currently loading 50k markers using Mapbox JS api and clustering them with leaflet.

There are two issues;

Firstly the JSON file is now 8mb

Secondly once the JSON file has loaded, the whole browser freezes while it processes it.

Is there any way of optimising this in either way?

Example data point:

```
[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":    ["-0.012336","51.531011"]},"properties":{"user_id":"15","title":Username"}}]
```

Code:

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map')
.setView([{{ $viewSettings['lat'] }},{{ $viewSettings['lng'] }}], {{ $viewSettings['zoom'] }})
.addLayer(L.mapbox.tileLayer('frasergillespie.llpnfb5a'));


$.getJSON('/mapLocations.json',function(geoJsonData){


var markers = L.markerClusterGroup({
    iconCreateFunction: function (cluster) {
        return new L.DivIcon({
            iconSize: [40,40],
            html: cluster.getChildCount(),
            className: 'cluster-icon'
        });
    },
    polygonOptions: {
        fillColor: '#fff',
        color: '#3cff91',
        weight: 1,
        opacity: 1,
        fillOpacity: 0.2
      }
});


var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(geoJsonData, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.title);
        layer.setIcon(L.icon({!! json_encode(Config::get('mapbox.iconJson')) !!}));
    }
});

markers.addLayer(geoJsonLayer);
map.addLayer(markers);
});
```

Comment: I had some thing similar I used elastic search to cluster all the points and then show clustered points this might help you https://github.com/cyrilcherian/million-points-on-map..now i can show a million points

Comment: I had performance issues with rendering a few hundred items and finally moved away from Leaflet 1.0-beta to WebGL by way of mapboxgljs. Processing 50k items (models-only) was no problem (on any client), even mobile, but the problem came when rendering. There are definitely ways to optimize how the data gets to the client and is setup/used. Floating point numbers are slower than integers, and they're strings in the sample. Possibly adjust the data structure...this is a fairly involved question but hope these high-level points are useful.